# Azure WebJobs SDK: Not calling message.complete() on a specific ServiceBus triggered function

Tags: azure, azure-webjobssdk, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a service bus triggered function of the following form:

```
public static void ProcessJobs([ServiceBusTrigger("topicname", "subscriptionname", AccessRights.Listen)] BrokeredMessage input, [ServiceBus("topic2name", "subscription2name", AccessRights.Send)] out BrokeredMessage output)
{
    output = new BrokeredMessage(input.GetBody<String>());
}
```

My use case is that this function simply takes messages from one topic and pushes them to another topic. I don't want to remove the message from the source topic in the process.

Is that possible to accomplish?

Additionally where can I find more information on the *AccessRights* and how they affect message access. For example: In the above example I am getting messages from the input topic with *AccessRights.Listen* but it still seems to be "removing" messages once function invocation is done on those messages.

Comment: Why don't you want to complete the message ?

Comment: @Thomas: Not sure if this is an anti-pattern but I was considering nesting service bus queues. So in this case I have a parent queue that hands off its item to the child queue. Once the child is done, the parent queue item is removed (along with the child queue item). This is more for the semantics of my application rather than for a specific technical reason.

Comment: so if you use a topic you can have multiple subscriptions and use Filter to handle communication between parent/children queues. If you don't complete the message, it will be available also so you ll reprocess it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jambor said the default behavior is to complete the message if the function finishes successfully (see [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/#how-servicebustrigger-works)) or abandon if the function fails.

You can see the implementation of this behavior in the [SDK Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/MessageProcessor.cs) looking at the code of the `MessageProcessor` class:

```
public virtual async Task CompleteProcessingMessageAsync(BrokeredMessage message, FunctionResult result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        if (!MessageOptions.AutoComplete)
        {
            // AutoComplete is true by default, but if set to false
            // we need to complete the message
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await message.CompleteAsync();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await message.AbandonAsync();
    }
}
```

**Interesting point : This is a virtual function.**

The `ServiceBusConfiguration` exposes a `MessagingProvider` property.

If you have a look at the code of the default `MessagingProvider` class in the [SDK Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/MessagingProvider.cs), you'll see that you can override the method that is responsible of creating new `MessageProcessor`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a <see cref="MessageProcessor"/> for the specified ServiceBus entity.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entityPath">The ServiceBus entity to create a <see cref="MessageProcessor"/> for.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="MessageProcessor"/>.</returns>
public virtual MessageProcessor CreateMessageProcessor(string entityPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityPath))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entityPath");
    }
    return new MessageProcessor(_config.MessageOptions);
}
```

**This function is also virtual.**

Now you can create your own `MessagingProvider` and `MessageProcessor` implementation:

```
public class CustomMessagingProvider : MessagingProvider
{
    private readonly ServiceBusConfiguration _config;

    public CustomMessagingProvider(ServiceBusConfiguration config) : base(config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public override MessageProcessor CreateMessageProcessor(string entityPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entityPath");
        }
        return new CustomMessageProcessor(_config.MessageOptions);
    }

    class CustomMessageProcessor : MessageProcessor
    {
        public CustomMessageProcessor(OnMessageOptions messageOptions) : base(messageOptions)
        {
        }

        public override async Task CompleteProcessingMessageAsync(BrokeredMessage message, FunctionResult result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await message.AbandonAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And configure your JobHost like that :

```
public static void Main()
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    var sbConfig = new ServiceBusConfiguration
    {
        MessageOptions = new OnMessageOptions
        {
            AutoComplete = false
        }
    };
    sbConfig.MessagingProvider = new CustomMessagingProvider(sbConfig);
    config.UseServiceBus(sbConfig);
    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

This was for the technical part of this question...

Now if you don't complete your message, the message will be available for the same function again and again until you reach the `MaxDeliveryCount` and then your message will be dead lettered. So even if design your function to be idempotent, I am pretty sure this is not what you want.

Maybe you should explain a little bit more what you try to achieve ?

If you are looking for parent-child queues communication (see question comments), there is a good article that explain how to design workflow with ASB :

- [Creating a Simple Workflow with Azure Webjobs and Service Bus](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/sspencer/post/2014/07/03/Creating-a-Simple-Workflow-with-Azure-Webjobs-and-Service-Bus)

Otherwise, you can have a look at the [`Defer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh143971.aspx) method on the BrokerMessage object:

> Indicates that the receiver wants to defer the processing for this message.

It will allow you to hold the parent message until child message has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to remove the message from the source topic in the process.

From [this document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/) we can know that the ServiceBusTrigger will call complete function after the trigger is finished. It is the default mode. Here is the snippet from that article:

> > The SDK receives a message in PeekLock mode and **calls Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully**, or calls Abandon if the function fails. If the function runs longer than the PeekLock timeout, the lock is automatically renewed.